# Generic parameter extends type but is in contravariant position and typescript can't unify it

Tags: typescript

I try to allow my function consumers to user wider type but I use this type in contravariant position and typescript complaints.

Simplified code:

```
function wrapper<T extends Event = Event>(node: HTMLElement) {
    const handler = (e: T) => console.log(e.cancelable);
    node.addEventListener("click", handler);
}
```

And I get error:

```
Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'T'. 'Event' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'Event'.
```

How can I express my intent so typescript would understand me?

[Link to working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAdwE4EMAOmCmqA8AKojgB5Q5gAmAzogKIBulUiAvA82FAHwAUYOFRwAuRAAlCAWQAy9ADY4AtiwCUiAN4AoRLr26ICGqwAW6aotTtEfUYkLq2PRIbA04igHTy4Ac1ueEOYQOPLoAEaKqgDcOvp6gsKe6FRUTCwyMMaUeHwARBDyMBAA1nkANIhmFngxWgC%20cUA)

Full code:

```
export function tracker(
  eventType: string,
  options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions
) {
  const stream: Stream<Event> = Stream.empty();

  function tracker(node: HTMLElement) {
    const handler = (event: Event) => stream.shamefullySendNext(event);
    node.addEventListener( eventType, handler, options);

    return {
      destroy: () => {
        node.removeEventListener(eventType, handler);
        stream.shamefullySendComplete();
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    stream,
    tracker,
  };
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are using generics at all or what your intent really is. Can you use `function wrapper(node: HTMLElement) { const handler = (e: Event) => console.log(e.cancelable); node.addEventListener("click", handler); }` instead, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/DWKXyw)?  If not, please elaborate on exactly what goes wrong.

Comment: In real code, in place of console.log, there’s function that pushes e to user land.  User could define generic and have guarantee that this value would be of specific type. 

I added full code to question.

Comment: You're going to get that error when you make a function that takes `T extends Event` because `T` could be something like `interface MyEvent extends Event { customProperty: string };` which would never be fulfilled by an event listener.

Comment: You could make it a generic of event type (`K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap`) rather than `Event` and we can pass that down to `addEventListener` which is a generic of event type, but the event type is always `"click"`?  You can add the generic to your `tracker` but I'm actually not getting any errors on that other than not knowing where to import `Stream` from (because you have `Event` instead of a specific event).

Comment: Is [this](https://tsplay.dev/vwjo1N) what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite confusing, but I believe that what you want is to refine based on the *event type* (ie. "click") rather than the *event*.

We cannot ever safely use a generic `T` that `extends Event` because this `T` could have any arbitrary additional properties. Consider the following example:

```
interface MyEvent extends Event {
 customProperty: string
};

const handler = (e: MyEvent) => console.log(e.cancelable);
```

No event listener would ever be able to execute the callback `handler` because their `event` lacks the property `customProperty`.  That's why you get the error that "Type 'Event' is not assignable to type 'T'."

We can however refine on event type because this is what `addEventListener` does.

```
addEventListener<K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>(
    type: K, 
    listener: (this: HTMLElement, ev: HTMLElementEventMap[K]) => any, 
    options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions
): void;
addEventListener(
    type: string, 
    listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, 
    options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions
): void;
```

`addEventListener` can be called with a generic specifying the event type name.  When that generic `K` is set, the type of the event that is passed as an argument to the callback is refined based on the `HTMLElementEventMap`.

We can make your `tracker` function depend on the same generic `<K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>`.  Now your `eventType` must be `K` and your handler must take `(event: HTMLElementEventMap[K])`.  Notice that we have narrowed the event, but we haven't allowed for extra properties to be added via `extends`.

```
export function tracker<K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>(
  eventType: K,
  options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions
) {
  const stream: Stream<HTMLElementEventMap[K]> = Stream.empty();

  function tracker(node: HTMLElement) {
    const handler = (event: HTMLElementEventMap[K]) => stream.shamefullySendNext(event);
    node.addEventListener<K>( eventType, handler, options);

    return {
      destroy: () => {
        node.removeEventListener(eventType, handler);
        stream.shamefullySendComplete();
      },
    };
  }

  return {
    stream,
    tracker,
  };
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/ewedBW)

Comment: After stating my question and reading your response I realize that my whole premise was wrong. Thanks! I'm still wondering if I could let user assert event type somehow. I'm thinking about scenario, where someone is listening to some web component event and it calls handler with some subclass of `CustomEvent`. I'm worried that typescript could not know about relation between `CustomEvent` subclass and event name ...